# How to compute portfolio weight of forward contract

Tags: portfolio, forward, weights

how would one formally calculate the portfolio weight of a Forward position?

Suppose I have 100 mio portfolio. I have 50mio in Tesla shares and I have 50mio in Microsoft shares, and I enter into a 1 year forward contract with notional 50mio to receive Apple shares at a price of K. (such that at inception the forward contract has 0 value).

What are my portfolio weights? is the weight of my forward contract 0 because it has economic value of 0 at inception?

At different times t >0, would the weight be computed using the mark-to-market value?

thanks a lot!

Comment: In general, when you have a derivative like this the "effective position" in the underlying is the Delta times the notional value of the underlying specified in the contract. For a forward the Delta is going to be 1 for a non-dividend paying stock when interst rates = 0.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. When using the delta*notional approach, would you also adjust for "virtual cash"? i.e. The cash you would have had to spent in case you bought it with pure equities instead of a leveraged position?